# date time and alphabet wise sort in html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i am new to web page developer, i need to sort my table in date wise and alphabet wise on click of table header

[image]

this is my table.... the data's inside the table are generated dynamically using ajax....

my need is

- on click of date header it should sort according to date
- on click of notify header it should sort according to alphabet

please give some ideas or suggestions about this .......

Comment: numerous jQuery plugins for tables, easy to find in web search

Answer (score 4):

I made example using jQuery library, and added it in http://jsfiddle.net/bURg4/2/

jQuery selector returns is array object, which has native array `sort` function .

```
$('table tbody tr').sort( function( a , b ) {

     // do compare here
});
```

Hope this will helps ..

copy and paste following code into a file .. rename it into `test.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-key="id" data-column="0" data-order="asc">id</th>
                    <th data-key="date" data-column="1" data-order="asc">date</th>
                    <th data-key="notify" data-column="2" data-order="asc">notify</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>31-03-2013 06:12:57 PM</td>
                    <td>gold</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>31-03-2013 06:14:57 PM</td>
                    <td>diamond</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>31-03-2013 06:10:57 PM</td>
                    <td>silver</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function getDate( str ) {

                var ar =  /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) ([AM|PM]+)/ 
                     .exec( str ) 

                return new Date(
                    (+ar[3]),
                    (+ar[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
                    (+ar[1]),
                    (+ar[4])+ ( ar[7]=='PM'? 12 :0 ),
                    (+ar[5]),
                    (+ar[6])
                );
            };

            $( function(){


                var sorter = {

                    order   : [1,-1],
                    column  : 0 ,
                    key     :'id' ,

                    setOrder : function( k ){

                        this.order  = ({ 
                            asc :[1,-1], desc:[-1,1] 
                        })[k] || this.order ;

                        return this;
                    },
                    setColumn : function( c ){

                        this.column  = c || this.column ;
                        return this;
                    },

                    setKey : function( k ) {
                        this.key  = k || this.key;
                        return this;
                    },

                    sort : function( els ) {

                        var sortFunc = this.key;

                        return els.sort( this[ sortFunc ]);        
                    },

                    getValue : function( a, b ){

                        return {
                            a : $(a).find('td:eq('+ sorter.column +')').text(),
                            b : $(b).find('td:eq('+ sorter.column+')').text()
                        }
                    },
                    comp : function( val ) {

                            if ( val.a == val.b ) {
                                return 0;
                            }

                            return  val.a > val.b ? 
                                    sorter.order[0]:sorter.order[1] ; 

                    },
                    id : function( a , b ){

                            var val = sorter.getValue(a,b);

                            val.a = parseInt( val.a , 10 );
                            val.b = parseInt( val.b , 10 );

                            return sorter.comp( val );        

                    },

                    notify : function( a , b ){

                            var val = sorter.getValue(a,b);
                            return sorter.comp( val );           

                    },
                    date : function( a , b ){

                            var val = sorter.getValue(a,b);

                            val.a = getDate( val.a );
                            val.b = getDate( val.b );

                            return sorter.comp( val ); 

                    }
                }

                $('table thead').on('click', 'th', function(){

                        var sorted = sorter.setOrder( $(this).attr('data-order') )
                                           .setColumn( $(this).attr('data-column') )
                                           .setKey( $(this).attr('data-key') )
                                           .sort(  $('table tbody tr') );


                        $('table tbody').empty().append( sorted );  

                        $('table thead th').not( this )
                                           .attr('data-order' ,'asc');

                        $(this).attr(
                            'data-order',  
                            ( $(this).attr('data-order') == 'asc' ? 'desc' :'asc') 
                        );

                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but can u help me without on load function

Comment: @Kumar which load function ? did u check jsfiddle ?

Comment: i tried your code it shows error(TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null) when i clicked the date column in my code....

Comment: i have made some change in question just see it when i applied the code it shows error(TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of null) in date column please help....

Comment: again the same error coming can u give fiddle for the changed table

Answer (score 2):

I would use a small jquery plugin.

I have tried http://www.datatables.net/ but think its too large for my need thats a little bigger than yours so I would suggest http://tablesorter.com/docs/ which fits you speification perfect.

You'll find demos on their sites.

Answer (score 2):

Store the corresponding values in an array and do sorting

To sort array by date, Use this

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
var c = new Date(a.date);
var d = new Date(b.date);
return c-d;
});
```

To sort array by alphabet , use basic [sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhwxr/1/) for sorting the date and time

Comment: See my edited post .. I have attached a link for sorting the date and time

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortAsc(a, b) {
    var aSort = a.Text.toLowerCase(), //Text is the field on which we make sort
        bSort = b.Text.toLowerCase();
    if (aSort === bSort) return 0;
    return aSort < bSort ? 1 : -1;
}
function sortDesc(a, b) {
    var aSort = a.Text.toLowerCase(), //Text is the field on which we make sort
        bSort = b.Text.toLowerCase();
    if (aSort === bSort) return 0;
    return aSort > bSort ? 1 : -1;
}
```

i use these two methods for sorting Json Obejct

call them as  `[jsonObject].sort(sortDesc) or  [jsonObject].sort(sortAsc)`

Comment: This will not sort dates correctly unless they are supplied as yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

You may give id for date column in increasing manner that is Row 1 col1 will be date_1 then row2 and col1 will be date_2 like that, apply it to both columns (notify_1,notify_2,...). Have a hidden field on form that consists the no of rows. on the basis of it you may apply a loop up to it then can use any sorting algo on td's inner html.