# JavaScript sort date without plugin

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a piece of code I use to sort columns in an HTML table and it works perfectly....except for date fields.  Alphabet and pure numeric it works great! but when used on a date column the sorter does not work as I want it to.  Currently dates get sorted like so:

> 01-02-2016
>
> 02-01-2016
>
> 12-12-2014
>
> 12-14-2015

What I want to have happen is:

> 12-12-2014
>
> 12-14-2015
>
> 01-02-2016
>
> 02-01-2016

Here is the JavaScript that I use to make this sort work currently:

```
var tb, asc1 = 1,
   asc2 = 1,
   asc3 = 1,
   asc4 = 1,
   asc5 = 1,
   asc6 = 1;
                
      function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
      var rows = tbody.rows,
                 rlen = rows.length,
                 arr = new Array(),
                 i, j, cells, clen;
      // fill the array with values from the table
         for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].cells;
            clen = cells.length;
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
            }
          }
       // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
           arr.sort(function (a, b) {
              return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
           });
       // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
           for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
              rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
           }
        }
```

The onclick function is this:

```
function test() {
   sort_table(tb, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc5 = 1; asc6 = 1;
};
```

How can I make this happen?  I am really new to JavaScript and still learning every day.  The date format is mm-dd-yyyy as per my example.

### Update

I have adopted Daniel Almeida code as he has it working in an example exactly as I want it to but I cannot incorporate it within my own code.  When I do the sort seems to be erratic and all over the place. I am now working with the following code:

```
var sorter = function(id, column, order, isDate) {
  var t = document.getElementById(id);
  var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(t.rows, 0);

  rows = rows.sort(function(a, b) {

  var dtA = (isDate) ? new Date(a.cells[column].innerHTML) : a.cells[column].innerHTML;
  var dtB = (isDate) ? new Date(b.cells[column].innerHTML) : b.cells[column].innerHTML;

  return (order == 0) ? dtA > dtB : dtA < dtB;

});

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  t.appendChild(rows[i]);
  }

}
```

I have also created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fybrej54/3/) but I can't get that to do anything at all. It worries me that I am missing something that I am not aware of.

The reason for splitting the two tables is the bottom table is dynamically loaded and the container div allows for a scroll window instead of a long list of information when there are 100s of returned records.

Comment: Store the actual date objects and sort those, instead of sorting the strings. Only convert the date objects to strings when they need to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example: [sort table](https://jsfiddle.net/5guypvhq/)

```
var sorter = function(td, id, column, isDate) {

    var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
    var rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbl.rows, 0);

    var order = td.getAttribute("order") == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
    td.setAttribute("order", order);

    rows = rows.sort(function(a, b) {

      var valA = a.cells[column].innerText;
      var valB = b.cells[column].innerText;

      var compA = (isDate) ? new Date(valA) : valA;
      var compB = (isDate) ? new Date(valB) : valB;

      if (order == "asc") {
        if (compA < compB) return -1;
        if (compA > compB) return 1;
      }

      if (order == "desc") {
        if (compA > compB) return -1;
        if (compA < compB) return 1;
      }

      return 0;

    });

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      tbl.appendChild(rows[i]);
    }

  }
```

EDIT: check this fiddle [working with date and text, asc and desc](https://jsfiddle.net/1s3sapdh/)

Comment: This is doing exactly what I want but I can't figure out how to incorporate this into my code above.  I want to be able to sort both by the text columns and the date columns.  Any idea on how I can combine the two to get the desired effect?  I am new so I am guessing I am looking over something really simple...

Comment: send the type as parameter.. should work fine.. `(id, column, order, type)` and check before converting to date.. `var dtA = (type == "date") ? new Date(a.cells[column].innerHTML) : a.cells[column].innerHTML;`

Comment: I added that piece of code but that seemed to go back to sorting the dates  as a number instead of a date.  Here is the jsfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5guypvhq/).  It works on the letter column perfectly but not the date...

Comment: I think you forgot to fork.. [check this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/xcb8zkar/)

Comment: This is perfect!!!!  Now I am just having a hard time integrating it into my code which is acting erratically for some reason...

Comment: thanks for your code!  It works perfectly but for some reason I cannot get it to work with my table.  I have to be overlooking something very simple but I can't tell what it is.  Would you be able to take a look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fybrej54/5/) and let me know what I am missing?  I would really appreciate it.  I am a newb at all coding so I know it has to be something simple...

Comment: @Craig Howell  I've made some changes to work with text and date properly.. [check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/1s3sapdh/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript's built in [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. An array of dates object can easily be sorted, like so:

```
var array = [
  new Date("01/02/2016"),
  new Date("02/01/2016"),
  new Date("12/12/2014"),
  new Date("12/14/2015")
];
array.sort();
```

Comment: I think is the cleaner solution!

Comment: It may be but the array is comprised of more than just dates. There are text columns and varchar columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get time from date object for each item

`var arr = [];`

`arr[i]= new Date(item_date_string).getTime();`

You can sort array of integer values, then fill array of equalent dates strings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery plugin for sorting dates you can refer to this answer also [sort date in html table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609012/date-time-and-alphabet-wise-sort-in-html-table-using-javascript)